# Get last visible word in UITextView with maximumNumberOfLines != 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView that has a maximum number of lines 3 :
`textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 3`

The text is longer than 3 lines, and I would like that the last word visible would be **more**.

E.g :
For the string :

> This string is pretty long and we would like to be able to identify the last word visible so we can display "more" instead of the word found.

For 3 lines, the text displayed is :

> This string is pretty long and we would like to be able to identify

The result that I'm looking for :

> This string is pretty long and we would like to be able to **more**

Is there any API in UITextView, or in the text container that would allow me to get that last word displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you the ilyapuchka **ReadMoreTextView** library which is on this [link](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView). It is the easiest way to achieve this and it is pretty lightweight.

You can install it with CocoaPods, just implement pod 'ReadMoreTextView' into the podfile and you can use it like this:

```
let textView = ReadMoreTextView()

textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor ..."

textView.shouldTrim = true
textView.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
textView.trimText = "Read more"
```

Comment: That works. Good to read the article created by the author of this lib : http://ilya.puchka.me/custom-uitextview-in-swift/.